# Getting Checkbox Value Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am setting my jquery mobile checkboxes like so..

```
 $("#checkbox-2a").attr("checked", settings.DEnabled).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Here is the markup

```
 <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" style="text-align:center;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2a" id="checkbox-2a" class="custom" />
            <label for="checkbox-2a">
                Enable D</label>
..
```

The checkboxes get checked correctly. But now when I want to retrieve a value with this code..

```
  settings.DEnabled = $("#checkbox-2a").attr("checked");
```

When I debug it returns 'checked', when I look at the markup eventhough the checkboxes are getting updated when the correct check bool in the ui. I dont see a 'checked' attribute in the markup.

How do I get/find the value of the checkbox?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`attr` doesn't return a boolean value, you can use `prop` method: http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-examples

```
settings.DEnabled = $("#checkbox-2a").prop("checked");
```

Or `is` method:

```
settings.DEnabled = $("#checkbox-2a").is(":checked");
```